# New_target column based on 3rd value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe:

```
source    target              
jan       feb                               
mar       apr                 
jun                       
feb       aug                                            
apr       jul                                            
oct       dec                     
aug       nov       
dec       may
```

The output dataframe would be:

```
source    target    new_target              
jan       feb       aug                        
mar       apr       jul                  
jun                              
feb       aug       nov                                     
apr       jul       jul                                           
oct       dec       may              
aug       nov       nov
dec       may       may
```

So the `new_target` column will have 3rd value: i.e (trace followed between source and target `jan->feb->aug->nov`, since `aug` is 3rd value, it is the output in `new_target` column)

Edit:

```
source    target    new_target              
jan       feb       aug                        
mar       apr       jul                  
jun                              
feb       aug       nov                                     
apr       jul                                                  
oct       dec       may              
aug       nov       
dec       may
```

Comment: You need to elaborate more on how you got the new_target column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `Series` created by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
s = df.set_index(['source'])['target']
#if possible duplicates in source
#s = df.drop_duplicates('source').set_index(['source'])['target']
df['new_target'] = df['target'].map(s).fillna(df['target'])
print (df)
  source target new_target
0    jan    feb        aug
1    mar    apr        jul
2    jun                  
3    feb    aug        nov
4    apr    jul        jul
5    oct    dec        may
6    aug    nov        nov
7    dec    may        may
```

EDIT:

```
s = df.set_index(['source'])['target']
#if possible duplicates in source
#s = df.drop_duplicates('source').set_index(['source'])['target']
df['new_target'] = df['target'].map(s)
print (df)
  source target new_target
0    jan    feb        aug
1    mar    apr        jul
2    jun               NaN
3    feb    aug        nov
4    apr    jul        NaN
5    oct    dec        may
6    aug    nov        NaN
7    dec    may        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, is there a way in which we can extract the 3rd value for every value in source, if the 3rd value is not available in target, then new_target would be null, sorry this logic that l have mentioned in comment would give different output again, so do I have to post it as new question or I could edit above here

Comment: I have added the output based on logic in comments as edit section

Comment: @pc_pyr - answer was edited. If need empty string instead `NaN` use `.fillna('')` like `df['new_target'] = df['target'].map(s).fillna('')`

Answer (score 0):

```
d = df.dropna().set_index('source').target.to_dict()
df['new_target'] = df.target.apply(lambda x: d.get(x,x))

    source  target  new_target
0   jan     feb     aug
1   mar     apr     jul
2   jun 
3   feb     aug     nov
4   apr     jul     jul
5   oct     dec     may
6   aug     nov     nov
7   dec     may     may
```